# Jquery Ajax with jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi all below is my code

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'myUrl',
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    'data': {
      // sample daa
    },
    'success': function (data) {
      alert("here::");
    },
    'error': function (jqxhr, status, errorThrown) {
      alert("Failure, Unable to recieve content : " + status)
      alert(jqxhr.responseText);
    })
})
```

I am using the jsonp as my url belongs to other domain and i am able to get the response code as 200 and i can able to see the data in response (Checcked in Firebug) but none of the success or error methods are executing.
Please help me on this

Update response(copied from firebug)

```
{"documents":[{"trans":"sdsd","orig":"How","translit":"Elā","src_translit":""}],"dict":[{"pos":"unknown","terms":["dgssdg","sgsd"],"entry":[{"word":"gsdg","reverse_translation":["method","treatment","recipe","attitude","how","retro"],"score":0.000305442198},{"word":"మార్గము","reverse_translation":["way","route","road","entry","how","impasse"],"score":0.000305442198}],"base_form":"how","pos_enum":20}],"src":"en","server_time":12}
```

Comment: Does the server actually return JSONP? If not you cannot use JSONP. Also please format your  code properly here, I believe all the spaces on the left hand side are unnecessary and don't increase readability.

Comment: @Felix it is returning the valid json data checked with jsonlint

Comment: But it has to return JSONP, not JSON! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP. JSON by itself is not valid JS, but JSONP requires the response to be JavaScript (a function call to be more precise).

Comment: Are the closing brackets *});* at the end missing just because you didn't copy paste them?

Comment: @FelixKling Can you please elaborate what changes i have to do, i can not change the datatype to json because it is a cross domain and the server will send the json data. will you please let me know the changes with above requirements to my function

Comment: Cleaned up the formatting for you, as requested by @FelixKling - do you have the server output for us to verify that it is in fact JSONP and not JSON being returned?

Comment: @Zero, you should change the server side script that you are calling so that it returns `JSONP` instead of `JSON`. There's nothing you could do on the client. Please read about the differences between JSONP and JSON in the Wikipedia article that Felix linked to in his previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because your server side script apparently is returning JSON instead of JSONP. Your server side script should be modified so that it returns JSONP if you want to be able to invoke it with a cross domain AJAX request.

You can read more about JSONP here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

So instead of:

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "trans": "sdsd",
            "orig": "How",
            "translit": "Elā",
            "src_translit": ""
        }
    ],
    "dict": [
        {
            "pos": "unknown",
            "terms": [
                "dgssdg",
                "sgsd"
            ],
            "entry": [
                {
                    "word": "gsdg",
                    "reverse_translation": [
                        "method",
                        "treatment",
                        "recipe",
                        "attitude",
                        "how",
                        "retro"
                    ],
                    "score": 0.000305442198
                },
                {
                    "word": "మార్గము",
                    "reverse_translation": [
                        "way",
                        "route",
                        "road",
                        "entry",
                        "how",
                        "impasse"
                    ],
                    "score": 0.000305442198
                }
            ],
            "base_form": "how",
            "pos_enum": 20
        }
    ],
    "src": "en",
    "server_time": 12
}
```

your server side script should return:

```
someCallback({
    "documents": [
        {
            "trans": "sdsd",
            "orig": "How",
            "translit": "Elā",
            "src_translit": ""
        }
    ],
    "dict": [
        {
            "pos": "unknown",
            "terms": [
                "dgssdg",
                "sgsd"
            ],
            "entry": [
                {
                    "word": "gsdg",
                    "reverse_translation": [
                        "method",
                        "treatment",
                        "recipe",
                        "attitude",
                        "how",
                        "retro"
                    ],
                    "score": 0.000305442198
                },
                {
                    "word": "మార్గము",
                    "reverse_translation": [
                        "way",
                        "route",
                        "road",
                        "entry",
                        "how",
                        "impasse"
                    ],
                    "score": 0.000305442198
                }
            ],
            "base_form": "how",
            "pos_enum": 20
        }
    ],
    "src": "en",
    "server_time": 12
})
```

where the client should be able to specify the name of the callback function (`someCallback`) by passing it as a query string parameter.

Then you could perform the cross domain AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/some_endpoint',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { firstName: 'john', lastName: 'smith' },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('Failure, Unable to recieve content : ' + status)
        alert(jqxhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, along with that i would like to know which part is stopping to execute success or error metod tough it is returning some data

Comment: It's the fact that your AJAX call is blocked by the same origin policy restriction that's built into browsers. Once you modify your server side script to return JSONP you will be able to successfully invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jsonp your code must look like this:

Example
Client side

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType    : "jsonp",
        url         : ' Some url ',
        data        : { some json data },
        // this is jsonp callback that use must to return from server side
        jsonpCallback : 'getResponse' 
    });
```

Server side must return something like this:

```
echo "getResponse({ some json data })";
```